# Using links to method's arguments in XML documentation leads to broken links in help file generated by SandCastle

Tags: .net, xml, documentation, sandcastle

I have a problem with proper resolving of link in `<see cref=""/>` tag when `<see>` points to a method's argument.

Here is an example:

```
<summary>
My method.
</summary>
<param name="arg1">Arg1</param>
<param name="arg2">Arg2</param>
<exception cref="ArgumentNullException">Either <see cref="arg1"/>
or <see cref="arg2"/> is <c>null</c></exception>
public void MyMethod(object arg1, object arg2)
{
  // code here...
}
```

After generating an XML documentation file both  tags are translated to:

```
<see cref="!:arg1"/>
<see cref="!:arg2"/>
```

When SandCastle is generating help file from above XML file such warnings occurs:

```
Warn: ResolveReferenceLinksComponent2: Unknown reference link target '!:arg1'
Warn: ResolveReferenceLinksComponent2: Invalid reference link target '!:arg1'
Warn: ResolveReferenceLinksComponent2: Unknown reference link target '!:arg2'
Warn: ResolveReferenceLinksComponent2: Invalid reference link target '!:arg2'
```

and after all the output help file contains broken links to both arg1 and arg2.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The <see> tag is not intended for referencing parameters. Use [<paramref>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wb7x2fhw.aspx) instead.

Comment: It works :) but I have another very simmilar problem:
`<see cref="string.Empty"/>` or `<see cref="bool.True"/>` also compile to `<see cref="!:string.Empty"/>` and `<see cref="!:bool.True"/>`

Comment: The String class (not C# data type) starts with capital S. So it should be <see cref="String.Empty"/> or even better <see cref="F:String.Empty"/>.For True, False, Null and other keywords use <see langword="true"/>. I'm using VSdocman but I believe Sandcastle knows langword attribute as well.